# How do I generate a unit test project along with my new project in Visual Web Dev Express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597(VS.100).aspx ...

> If you are using the Standard or
>   Express editions of Visual Studio, the
>   Create Unit Test Project dialog box is
>   not displayed. Instead, the new MVC
>   application project is generated
>   without a test project.

Does this mean it can't be done? If it can, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2009/04/nunit-template-for-aspnet-mvc.html) solution or just manually create a test project in visual c# express.